# How to share variables between Yacc parser and external program?

Tags: c, postgresql

I have written a parser in Yacc that sets some global variables during parsing. Now I want to pass these variables to another C program to do further processing. What is the best way to communicate or share variables between the Yacc parser and the external Libpq program?

Some options I've considered:

- Define the global variables in a shared header file that both the parser and external program include. But this seems hacky.
- Write the variables to a file or pipe in the parser, and read them from the external program. But this adds complexity.
- Link the two programs together and just access the global vars directly. But I'm not sure if this is possible or advisable.

Comment: The question is unclear about how many programs are involved.  Yacc generates a parser *function*, which is generally intended to be integrated into a larger program, but you talk about an *external program* with which the parser communicates, and about using pipes, which is common for separate processes, but much less so for communication within a single process.

Comment: Perhaps the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq.html) contains what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you say "external program" you must mean the *host* program that is calling the yacc-generated parser function, and that when you talk about "two programs" you must actually mean two *functions* in the same program.  This is consistent with how `yacc` is generally used.

With respect to your proposed options:

> - Define the global variables in a shared header file that both the parser and external program include. But this seems hacky.

It's not just hacky.  It has undefined behavior.  The variables involved need to have external linkage to be accessible by name from more than one translation unit, but external variables may not be defined more than once in the same program.  Putting *definitions* of them in a header and then including that header in multiple TUs contributing to the same program produces multiple definitions.

You can *declare* the variables in a header, and you should do if you mean to use variables for your data exchange, but you must accompany that with a single definition of each somewhere else.  Maybe in the yacc-generated source file, for instance.

> - Write the variables to a file or pipe in the parser, and read them from the external program. But this adds complexity.

This indeed seems unnecessarily complex, especially if the data to be communicated is itself complex.

> - Link the two programs together and just access the global vars directly. But I'm not sure if this is possible or advisable.

It is *normal* for the parser function to be linked into the same program as any other functions that consume data produced by a parse.  Indeed, I'm having trouble distinguishing this from your first option, as a header does nothing for you with regard to sharing data among separate programs.  See also my initial comments about how I'm interpreting the question.

There is also at least one other option:

- the parser can pass data about the progress or results of the parse by *calling functions* provided by the program for that purpose.

---

Overall, if you want your yacc-generated parser function to provide any data other than whether the parse succeeds, then you have to use semantic actions in your grammar to achieve that.  These are written in C, more or less, and they have the data sharing abilities of other C code: modify accessible objects in memory or call functions (possibly, but not necessarily, I/O functions).  What details are best for your particular scenario depend on details that you have not disclosed, but there is nothing inherently wrong with either.

Comment: I think i would go for the first options it seems clean to me.